# is authentication with client side rendered app and sessions possible?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session, react-router

No matter how I reason about it, it seems as if there is no secure way of implementing a client side rendered single-page-application that uses/accesses information on sessions for authentication, either via cookies, without severe compromise in security. I was mainly looking to building a React app, but it seems as if I will need to build it with SSR for a relatively secure version of authentication.

The use case that I'm especially thinking of is where the user logs in or registers and then gets a cookie with the session id.  From there, in a server side implementation, I can simply set up conditional rendering depending on whether the server stored session has an associated user id or not and then pull the user information from there and display it.

However, I can't think of a client-side rendered solution where the user can use the session id alone on the cookie that isn't easily spoofable.  Some of the insecure implementations would include using browser storage (local/session).  Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into JWTs? (https://jwt.io/) Storing a token in the cookie or even local storage is completely secure.

Answer (score 7):

I think the major issue here is that you are mixing the two parts of a web page (at least according to what HTML set out achieve) and treating them both as sensitive information.

You have two major parts in a web page - the first being the display format and the second being the data. The presumption in client side rendering / single page applications is that the format itself is not sensitive, and only the data needs to be protected.

If that's the case you should treat your client-side redirect to login behavior as a quality of life feature. The data endpoints on your server would still be protected - meaning that in theory an unauthenticated user could muck about the static HTML he is being served and extract page layouts and templates - but those would be meaningless without the data to fill them - which is the protected part.

In practice - your end product would be a single page application that makes requests to various API endpoints to fetch data and fill in the requested page templates. You wouldn't even need to go as far as storing complex session states - a simple flag notifying the client if it is authenticated or not would suffice (that is beyond what you would normally use for server-side authentication such as cookies or tokens)

Now let's say I'm a malicious user who is up to no good - I could "spoof" - or really just open the browser dev tools and set the isAuthenticated flag to true letting me skip past the login screen - now what would I do? I could theoretically navigate to my-service/super-secret without being redirected locally back to the login page on the client side - and then as soon as the relevant page tries to load the data from the server with the nonexistent credentials it would fail - best case displaying an error message, worst case with some internal exception and a view showing a broken template.

So just to emphasize in short:

A. If what you want to protect is your *TEMPLATE* then there is no way to achieve this clientside.

B. If what you want to protect is your *DATA* then you should treat gating/preventing users from navigating to protected pages as a quality of life feature and not a security feature, since that will be implemented on the server when serving the data for that specific page.

Comment: I just read this cause I had the same question and it really helped me to understand the issue better.